# In the early universe, could there have been "atoms" made of $W$ bosons?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, big-bang

I'm wondering if there ever could have been a time in our universe's history during which the charged W bosons could have combined to form a kind of short-lived "atom".

For example, we know that electrons and positrons can combine to form positronium, and we also know that antimuons and electrons can combine to produce muonium. But what about the W+ and W-? Could they have combined into a kind of "atom" back when the universe was a lot hotter and denser?

Comment: Hi Kolo, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Would you mind elaborating a bit on why you think this might be the case? Thanks!

Comment: Well, we know that electrons and positrons can combine to form positronium, and we also know that antimuons and electrons can combine to produce muonium.  But what about the W+ and W-?  Could they have combined into a kind of "atom" back when the universe was a lot hotter and denser?

Comment: Thanks for explaining that! I added it to your question so it is easier for everyone to read.

Comment: Have you estimated the lifetime of the W-onium and compared it to the lifetime of the Ws?

Comment: [Bound states of vector bosons](http://dspace.library.uu.nl/bitstream/handle/1874/4790/14102.pdf?sequence=2) - [Phenomenological consequences of a bound state of weak vector bosons](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02903036)

Comment: But *that* paper, written 30 yrs ago, assumed a now excluded strongly-coupled Higgs...  Scaling down from the OP's inspiration of positronium, the lifetime of the constituent Ws is 10 orders of magnitude shorter than the lifetime of such an electromagnetically bound onium. $10^{-25}s<<10^{-15}s$, no?

Comment: Further to @CosmasZachos's point, estimate the typical kinetic energy of a particle in an ensemble hot enough for free $W^\pm$ to persist, and compare to the binding energy of $W$-onium.  Positronium is made from *stopped* positrons in electron-rich matter --- that is, positrons cooled to effectively zero temperature.

Answer (score 3):

While the density and temperature of the early universe could have allowed a condensate of W bosons, in equilibrium with W decay products, this high temperature would also likely prevent the formation of bonds. For the same reason there were no stable hydrogen atoms until the universe cooled sufficiently.

Answer (score 1):

An atom-like configuration of a $W^+$ and $W^-$ requires electromagnetic interactions between them. The characteristic timescale for electromagnetic interactions is $10^{-14}$ to $10^{-20}$ seconds (source: http://www.ph.surrey.ac.uk/partphys/chapter6/nature.html). Meanwhile, the $W$ boson lifetime is around $10^{-25}$ seconds, which is at least 5 orders of magnitude smaller than the characteristic time for electromagnetic interactions.

Answer (score -2):

Well it is highly unlikely the formation of these atoms with W+ and W- bosons. Even if they did form they would immediately decay. Even in the early universe, these particles ae unstable. Or the W+ and W- could fuse to form a few Z bosons or Higgs bosons and the onium would fall apart.