# Can there be bound states of two $Z$ bosons or of a $W^+$ and a $W^-$ boson?

Tags: standard-model, weak-interaction, electroweak

Obviously, the Z and W are extremely short-lived.
But could they form bound states?

Such bound states would be the weak analogon of glueballs.
Have they been studied? Or is beyond-standard-model physics needed?

Curiosity keeps me awake... (And [In the early universe, could there have been "atoms" made of $W$ bosons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/293475) is not clear enough on the issue.)

So far, the feedback, also in the comments, has been that the characteristic time of the weak interaction is too long compared to the decay time of the Z and W bosons. Is this a hard argument? Are there any papers on this?

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/336834/are-there-bound-elementary-bosons).

Comment: They have been fantasized about and dismissed, again and again. As you may see from the linked questions, the lifetime of these gauge bosons is fantastically short, and the energy needed to have them roil out spontaneously is far in excess of their binding energy... EM, weak, or even Higgs-self coupling. Glueballs are different by dint of the strong force and confinement.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Sorry, what does "roil" mean exactly in this context? And "dint"? As a foreigner, I do not know these words, and I hear them for the first time.

Comment: There are online dictionaries. "By dint" = "by virtue". "Roil" suggests a hot bubbling medium with enough energy to produce real Ws, which, as I suggested, ensure you are above the *tiny* binding energy of any hypothesized "molecules". You can't win! I gather you have understood [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/295901/66086) in the question linked!